# Constraint constant changes but layout doesn't get updated?

Tags: swift, layout, tableview, view, cell

I have a strange problem: in my table view I want to update a single cell when its `UISlider` gets modified (value changed control event). At the moment the value of the slider changes, I want to animate a button into the cell (sliding in from the right). I set the constant of the button's constraint to -50 to make sure it's not visible by default, and when the slider's value gets changed, a method gets called which updates the table view, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called again for all cells in my table. Simplified it looks something like this:

```
func valueChanged(sender:UISlider) {
    // Reload table view
    self.myTableView.reloadData()

    // Let table view know the value of the slider got modified
    self.didChangeValueOfSlider = true
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm keeping track of which cell's slider got changed by using a custom `selectedCellIndexPath` variable. When the table view gets to the cell that got modified: it runs the following code:

```
    // Check if cell is selected
    if indexPath == self.selectedCellIndexPath {

        // Check if value of slider was changed
        if self.didChangeValueOfSlider == true {

            // Value was changed: set constraint back to default
            saveButtonTrailingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(15)
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

            // Reset slider update status
            self.didChangeValueOfSlider = false
        }
    }
```

Calling those `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` and `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` might be overkill or unnecessary, but please note this is my 15th attempt or so to actually get the view to display the updated layout. I used breakpoints to confirm the constant actually changes, after the code above is finished running and everything works perfectly fine. The only thing I can't get working is the updating part. I've tried `UIView.animateWithDuration` to animate the change, and I've tried methods like `layoutIfNeeded()` and `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates` of the table view: nothing works. What could be the reason the layout doesn't get updated? And what am I supposed to be calling the `layout` and `update` methods on? I've been calling them on `self.view` but I'm not even sure if you're supposed to be calling it on the view if you're trying to update the layout of a table view cell. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A common "gotcha" is that you don't call `reloadData` on the main thread and so the UI isn't updated. You can see if that is the case if you set a breakpoint in your `valueChanged` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and then in the debugger check which thread your are running at (should be Thread 1, com.apple.main-thread). Hope that is your problem too :)

Comment: @pbodsk No, the main thread is definitly not the problem. For one, I'm not running any other code in a different thread, so reloadData is being called on the main thread, just like all the other code. Two, if that was the problem, the UI would still be updated, only with a slight delay (because code on the main thread gets run first). However, in my case the UI doesnt get updated at all. And lastly, the debugger would give me a warning if I was making layout changes on a background thread, even without setting a breakpoint. I'm not getting any warning at all.

Comment: OK, I just thought it was worth checking if that was the case :)

Comment: Are you using constant cell height or dynamic cell height?I guess this is an issue with constraints settings.

Comment: @user3608500 All cells are equal in height, except for the selected cell, which increases height on the moment it is selected. Regardless of what the cell height is, however, the button Im trying to animate is perfectly visible in its default state (CGFloat of 15) but after it's animated from -50 to 15, it doesn't appear anymore, so I don't understand how constraint settings could be causing the problem.

Comment: Oh..one more thing. How is your `saveButtonTrailingConstraint` defined? Could it be that it somehow goes out of scope/looses its value? (if it is defined with `weak` for instance)

Comment: @pbodsk I defined the button to which the constraint belongs by assinging the cell's viewWithTag to a constant, and after that I defined the constraint of that button by accessing the button's constraints property, which returns an array of all constraints that belong to the button. I've tried modifying the constant of that constraint to several different values and it always shows the change at runtime, so the connection with the constraint is probably not the issue. Setting the constraint goes flawless, animating or updating it doesn't for some reason...

Comment: @pbodsk Turns out you were pretty close. The problem was INDEED the constraint itself. It didn't lose connection, however, I was accessing the WRONG constraint. I defined it as `saveButtonTarilingConstraint` but I was actually modifying was the `saveButton`'s width constraint (which apparently can't be animated). Instead of accessing `saveButton.constraints[indexOfTrailingConstraint]` I should have defined `saveButton.superview!.constraints[indexOfTrailingConstraint]` as the constraint belongs to the superview and not to the button itself.

Comment: Haha...nothing like finding something like that after having spent the better part of a day scrathing your head and shouting at the computer :) glad you found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem turned out to be the constraint itself. as I was accessing the wrong one. I defined it as `saveButtonTrailingConstraint` but I was actually modifying was the `saveButton`'s width constraint (which apparently can't be animated). Instead of accessing `saveButton.constraints[indexOfTrailingConstraint]` I should have defined `saveButton.superview!.constraints[indexOfTrailingConstraint]` as the constraint belongs to the superview and not to the button itself. I guess the best thing to take away from this clumsy mistake is to always double-check if you're modifying the correct constraint if you're doing it programmatically, because it doesn't always show on the first eye.